# How to read file and find it in folders

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

We have requirement where we are searching file(s) in folders in a specific path. The .csv file which contains list of file names and we want to find those files in the given directory.
   If any of the files mentioned in the .csv file is missing in the search path then it should throw error message.

We tried with below script but it is not working:

```
set InputFile=C:\Users\336727\Desktop\arun\SearchMCSentry\inputs.csv
:start
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('type "%InputFile%"') do ( 
    set "Found=1" 
        for /R %%f in ("%%A") do ( 
    echo ---%%f and Found = %Found%
            if exist %%f  (
            set Found=2
    echo ====%%A and Found = %Found%
            pause
            )
    echo %%A and Found = %Found%
        )
    if %Found%==1 goto :error

    )
    :error
    echo File not found
```

Could you pls help us how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Parag

Comment: Please search SO using the facility in the top bar for `delayed expansion`. That should explain why your expectations of the value of `found` are not being fulfilled. The entire body of your `for..%%A...` could be replaced by `if not exist "%%A" goto error`, disposing of the flag problem completely.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not a problem statement. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have fell into the trap of [delayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

---

## What is Delayed Expansion

In old batch scripts running on DOS, variables are expanded(turned into its value) when the line is ran. That means, all variables in the `for` loop are expanded when the processor starts executing the `for` loop.

## Your Case

The variable `%found%` is not set before(at least what I can see). Therefore, when the loop runs, these happens:

```
if ==1 goto :error
```

## How-to fix

Enable delayed expansion(let expansion occur at run-time, not phrase-time). Add this line before your loop:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

and change `%found%` to `!found!` so that the processor will understand the need to expand it at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternate Method - `CALL SET`

If you don't like `delayed expansion`, you can use `call set` to emulate the effect.

```
call set found=1
call echo %%found%%
```

This `call command` tricks work on all commands except `for`, `if`. `CALL REM` only works partially.

Unless absolutely necessary, I recommend to use `delayed expansion`. `CALL SET` is slower.